# Android OpenGL ES 1.0 lighting position, direction and cutoff

Tags: android, opengl-es, lighting

I'm trying to create a spotlight in my 2D game using the following code

```
float[] ambient = {0.1f, 1, 1, 1};
float[] position = {45, 20, 0, 1};
float[] direction = {0, -1, 0};

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT1);
gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, ambient, 0 );
gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_POSITION, position, 0);
gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, direction, 0);
gl.glLightf(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 30.0f);
```

In general the spot is working, but I cannot move it, nor change the direction and cutoff.
When I change the position vector it eighter stays in the same position or completely disappears. The same happens with direction and cutoff. It Alway shines left/up with an angle of 45 degrees. When I change GL_AMBIENT to GL_DIFFUSE or GL_SPECULAR, the light disappears as well. The only thing I can change is the color of the light.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that gles10 only does per-vertex-lighting. a per-pixel-lighting has to be implemented for this to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in fixed pipeline, the position of the light is transformed by the top of the matrix stack at the time `glLightf(GL_POSITION)` is called.

Therefore if you want to define your light's position in world coordinates, you must already have the ViewProjection matrix on top the stack.

It's a common mistake, many people define the light's position in world coordinates before they setup their camera/projection matrix, so it actually gets defined in screen space coordinates.

Comment: btw when i do gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); just before enabling the light, it shows up on each face...